# Prism 7.2 How to inject an instance into ViewModel another Module

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, prism, akka.net

i'm a new in a development of WPF applications with PRISM and AKKA.NET frameworks.

In my code for Shell Window I made an instance of ActorSystem.

```
 public partial class App
{
    private ActorSystem appActorSystem;
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        appActorSystem = ActorSystem.Create(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetName().Name);
        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance(appActorSystem);
    }


    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog)
    {
        moduleCatalog.AddModule<CommandBar.CommandBarModule>();
    }

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        appActorSystem.Terminate();
        appActorSystem.Dispose();
        base.OnExit(e);
    }
}
```

The instance will be registered in DI Container (Unity) after creation.

In my application i have also a module.

```
 public class CommandBarModule : IModule
{
    private IContainerProvider _containerProvider;
    public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
        _containerProvider = containerProvider;
        var appActorSystem = _containerProvider.Resolve<ActorSystem>();

        var regionManager = _containerProvider.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(regionNames.CommandBar, typeof(ViewA));
    }


    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ViewA>();
    }
}
```

I want to get the instance of the Actorsystem in the module. It works fine in CommandBarModule  Class.

But I want also to get the instance of my Actorsystem in the ViewModel of the module...

```
 public class ViewAViewModel : BindableBase
{

    private string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _message, value); }
    }


    public ViewAViewModel()
    {

        Message = "test";
    }
}
```

My First Idea was, that i can do injection of IContainerProvider into the constructor of the ViewModel, like this:

```
public class ViewAViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private IContainerProvider _containerProvider;

    private string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _message, value); }
    }


    public ViewAViewModel(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
        _containerProvider = containerProvider;
        var appActorSystem = _containerProvider.Resolve<ActorSystem>();

        Message = "test";
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work...

Could you please explain me how to do it right?

Comment: Did you try to inject the view model with an `ActorSystem` instead of an `IContainerProvider`?

Answer (score 1):

Inject the dependency, not the container:

```
public ViewAViewModel(ActorSystem appActorSystem)
{
    Message = "test";
}
```

It does not matter in which module a service is registered and where it is resolved, as long as it's resolved *after* being registered.

Comment: Many thanks. Your solution works great. Could you explain the mechanism of its work? I did not find relevant documentation or examples.

Comment: That would be far too much for a comment, I'd rather suggest reading a few books on "Dependency Injection" or "Inversion of Control". Very short summary: you register types with the container, telling him the desired lifespan, by using the `ViewModelLocator` you tell prism to let the container create the view models, and when doing that, the container produces all the required constructor parameters (e.g. creating new ones when appropriate by the requested lifespan). For the prism-specific part, this is a good read: https://brianlagunas.com/getting-started-prisms-new-viewmodellocator/